# How to debug Invalid block type 'banners/banners'

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, debugging

I have an invalid block type 'banners/banners', I have been trying to locate this error for the last couples days, but unsuccessful. I search through my code base, and there is no sign of `banners/banners` or `Mage_Banners_Block_Banners`. I see that there is `Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` in stacktrace, but I look through the locale/yyy/email/template, I still cannot find reference of `banners/banners`. Please help

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Banners_Block_Banners' in /var/www/html/xxx/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('banners/banners', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('banners/banners', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/xxx/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(548): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<!-- --Baner --...')
#6 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Page.php(101): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<!-- --Baner --...')
#7 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(577): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('cms_page', true)
#10 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#11 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#16 /var/www/html/xxx/app/design/frontend/ma_vanese/ma_vanesa2/template/page/1column.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#17 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/webfahasa...')
#18 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ma_van...')
#19 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '43')
#25 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '43')
#26 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#27 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /var/www/html/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /var/www/html/xxx/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /var/www/html/xxx/index.php(89): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

Comment: Did you check your database (transaction email tables)?

Comment: Check your CMS pages, like your home page or others, in admin. The banners/banners block may be lurking in the content section of one of those

Comment: @R.S: I did `select * from fhs_core_email_template where template_text like '%banner%';` and it return nothing.

Comment: @kaska: Thank you, by looking at table `cms_page`, and `cms_block`, I am able to locate the block. Thank you very much. If you want the accept, please create your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your CMS pages, like your home page or others, in admin. The banners/banners block may be lurking in the content section of one of those

Comment: Table to search include, `cms_page`, `cms_block` and `core_email_template`.